# Jquery .Post problem

Tags: jquery

For some reason, this is not submitting to the server.

```
function get(){
    $.post('something_help.php', name: 'blah',function(output) {
        alert(output);
    });
}
```

---

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) object is not correct in your syntax. It has to be a map or a string.

Do (notice the paranthesis):

```
$.post('something_help.php', {name : 'blah'},function(output){
   alert(output);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the data should be well formed json or a key/value pair string which is wrong in your case.

```
$.post('something_help.php', { name : 'blah' },function(output){
            alert(output);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems with your code.

- get is reserved in newer versions of JavaScript. This won't fail, but it's bad form
- you're passing in name: 'blah', which is incorrect

  - try "{blah: 'name'}" to send JSON